# Populate Select using ViewBag without using html Helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I Have this in my controller

```
ViewBag.list = new SelectList(db.ListOfDB, "Value", "Text");
```

I need to create a Select, but without using the @Html.DropDownList I try to use this:

```
<select id="mylist"> ??? (selectitem) @ViewBag.list ??? </select>
```

How create select based from Viewbag, but not use Html.Helper

Comment: Just curious to know, Is there a reason why you do not want to make the helper method call, but write yourself all the code to build the SELECT element ?

Comment: For two reason. Just learn and make my owner helper..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass your list to the view on your model. You could then do

```
<select id="myList">
@foreach(var item in Model.myList)
{
   <option value="@item.Value">item.Name</option>
}
</select>
```

Comment: There is a simple error. The option tag is not closed properly in the above answer.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me but I think you missed two "@" on the option tag. On my case I had to use: <option value="@item.Value">@item.Name</option>

Comment: @newhouse-pt Thanks! I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

After many attempts, this one worked for me

This one in the Controller -

```
ViewBag.ilist = new SelectList(db.tblPersons.Where(d => d.PersonTyp == "SUPPLIER").ToList(), "slno", "PersonName");
```

'slno' being the Id column and 'PersonName' being the 'Data' column

Then in Razor page (Without HTML helpers)

```
<select id="dpdnperson" name="dpdnperson" class="dropdown btn bg-gradient-primary" style="color:white; width:100%" Font-Size="Medium">
                <option>-- SELECT --</option>
                @foreach (var item in ViewBag.ilist)
                {
                    <option value="@item.Value" >@item.Text</option>
                }
            </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

@{

```
ViewBag.Title = "";

Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutLanding.cshtml";

List<SelectListItem> list = ViewBag.list;
```

}

```
@for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{

         <option value="@list[i].Value">@list[i].Text</option>
 }
```